# Can MatLab 'catch' be at higher level than 'try'?

Tags: matlab, try-catch

Is it possible in MatLab to throw an exception in a nested function, and have it 'caught' by a higher up function, such as in C++ or Visual Basic?

Comment: Do you mean [`rethrow`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rethrow.html)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Does not  `throw` fit better here? OP does not write anything about throwing an exception again after catching it. I think that what he wants is to `throw` an exception and catch it higher up in the stack. If the exception is not thrown explicitly, this seems to be automatic for all exception that is matlab exceptions as well (for example index out of bounds and so on).

Comment: If you can  throw it and leave it uncaught until the higher level, yes (I'm not really sure know how it works).

Comment: If there is an exception several functions deep, we want execution to continue from the top function, where it will return an error code to the calling C code.   We are using Matlab-coder to translate Matlab code into C++.  Main program is C++, which calls Matlab-generated C++, which needs to return an error code to calling C++ if Matlab exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible to catch exceptions in a higher level then they occur. What I do not think works, is to catch exceptions on another level than where the try is. I am not sure about that though. The try catch is fairly simple to implement in matlab. It really solves itself in some auto- magical way. It is possible to throw exceptions inside try block and then it will be caught in the catch. It is also possible to just surround the code that may go wrong inside a try block and then catch the exception.

Using throw:

```
function mymain()
    x=[1,2];
    try
        myfun(x);
    catch me
        disp(me);
        error(me.message);
    end
end

function myfun(x)
    if (length(x)>1)
        throw(MException('MATLAB:badsubscript','x must be scalar!'));
    end
end
```

Using nothing:

```
function mymain2()
    x=[1,2];
    try
        myfun2(x);
    catch me
        disp(me);
        error(me.message);
    end
end

function myfun2(x)
    x(7);
end
```

The variable `me` is not defined in the sense that you yourself actually defines a variable `me`. It is rather matlab that creates an exception and then the exception is stored in the variable defined in the catch.